# How to return to a specific navigation stack in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

So I have the following issue:

On my home page, I have a list of folders in which I can enter. So I currently have this navigation stack: Home (no folder) > Home (folder 1) > Home (folder 2) > Home (folder 3) .. and so on (all with a back button, except the first one)

On the last page, I have an action to move a file .. which takes me to other screens that take care of the move.
Once the move is done, I would like to return to the previous navigation stack (in the last folder I was on when I selected the file).

I haven't found a way to do that, since setPages use different pages (but here I am on the same page, just different iterations of it).

Comment: when navigating pages are you using navCtrl.push() method?

Comment: yes, I am using the push method

Comment: do you use `pop()` method?